# md-autocomplete and ng-class

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I would like to style the first 10 items in an autocomplete list to have a green background.

I tried adding ng-class to the md-autocomplete element, but it didn't seem to "take"

1. does md-autocomplete support ng-class?
2. any suggestions on how I might accomplish my goal?

Comment: Can you show some code or create a fiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go - [CodePen](https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/Mbjvqb)

Markup (relevant)

```
<md-item-template>
    <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i" ng-class="{greenBackground: $index<=9}">{{item.display}}</span>
</md-item-template>
```

CSS

```
.greenBackground {
  background: green;
}
```

Comment: DOH!  Always forget the template

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the [documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdAutocomplete) you can use `md-menu-class` to style the dropdown menu.